# How to get event of mouse and keyboard using UIAutomation

Tags: c#, user-interface

I try to create test tool application use C# UIAutomation library.
The example code is:

```
Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(
   new AutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(OnAutomationFocusChanged));
```

When I detect focus changed, I need to get type of event(left/right click or keyboard pressed).
Is it possible to do this an How can I find these value in method OnAutomationFocusChanged()?

Answer (score 2):

**Refer Following code:**

```
public static void RightClick(this AutomationElement element)
    {
     var ev = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Right);
     ev.RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseDownEvent;
     this.OnMouseDown(ev);
    }
```

**Also refer this:**

[Move mouse with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185916/move-mouse-with-c-sharp)

Hope its helpful.

Comment: THanks, but I need to detect mouse and keyboard event instead of send mouse and keyboard event.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible with UI automation. Low-level interactions like mouse and keyboard events are not part of the API. The API is designed around higher-level interactions like `Invoke` in the `InvokePattern` or `Select` in the `SelectionItemPattern`. There are events for those kinds of interactions, but nothing for detecting key presses or mouse movement/clicks/drags.

The only way I know of to get these events would be through global hooks in the windows api. This [project](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/) seems like it might be a good place to start.