# Moving cursor position?

Tags: .net, vb.net

With the below code, I want to shift the cursor on the screen to the point (200,200) which works fine, but when I move the mouse (with my hand) the cursor immediately returns to its original location. What am I doing wrong?

I am running `XP` on a `KVM` virtual machine running on a `linux` host - not that this should effect how this program runs.

I have also tried other methods suggested by various bulletin boards but they all get the same effect.

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(200, 200)
    End Sub
End Class

Thank-you for your comments.

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits Windows.Forms.Form



    ' Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()

        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '

        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(292, 266)

        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub


End Class


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim abc As New Point
        abc.Offset(200, 200)
        Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(abc)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The partial class above was generated by the integrated development environment. The last section only contains your suggested code. So I have done nothing with regard to any
"Mouse Move" event.  However, in a past test I made a Protected Override Sub for the the on Mouse Move  and my code would step through this sub in debug mode
when I moved the cursor. The thinking behind this that if I override the sub in the base class - I could prevent it from doing anything in the base class
with mouse move ( . such as moving the cursor back to its original location ) . I am not sure however whether my override class prevented this
or perhaps the cursor is being moved back to its original location by another method in the base class - which I can not see.

Is it possible to be able to debug and step into code that is part of the base class - this way I could see exactly what is going on. Currently when I step into
debugging, it only shows my methods in my classes not methods in the base class.

Comment: Maybe remove that `system`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I tried on windows xp 32-bit native - no virtual machines and the cursor.position = new point (200,200) works as expected. So the problem must be with my virtual machine set up. I tried it on both Virtual Box and KVM and both did not handle the cursor position command properly.

Comment: When I configured my virtual machine to lock the cursor to the guest VM OS, ( ie where you have to press CTRL-ALT to release the cursor from VM  ) the setting of cursor.position through the code has the same effect as on a native OS ( non-virtual )  - eg It worked properley

When the mouse could move freely between VM desktops and host desktop - then the cursor was not moving properly.     Thank-you for everyones help.

Answer (score -1):

## Explanation

We will take any variable and declare it as `New Point`. The next step we will do is define place of `abc` variable using the `offset` control. And finally Move the mouse to `abc`.

## Code And Example

```
abc.Offset(200, 200)
Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(abc)
```

I hope it works pefectly!

Comment: When I type the above , into my code so it is now Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      dim abc as new point  abc.Offset(200, 200)
Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(abc)
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: I also receive a warning saying Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

Comment: When I type the above , into my code so it is now Public Class Form1 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load dim abc as new point abc.Offset(200, 200) Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(abc) End Sub End Class.       the cursor moves , but moves right back to original location after I move the mouse a fraction

Comment: Then, it is problem with your code. Check your code twice-thrice. If you don't find the error, update some more code and I will update my answer or tell you what's wrong. You may have something under `mousemove` or such relevant events that is forcing cursor go back to the original position. This is no co-incidence that your code and mine both are getting the same error, there is something that is pushing it to the original location. Just check your code and update it.

Comment: Thank-you for your comments.         My entire code is  ` Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim abc As New Point
        abc.Offset(200, 200)
        Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(abc)
        abc.Offset(500, 500)
        Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(abc)
    End Sub
End Class`

Comment: Is your code just this, I mean nothing else? In this too, why are you changing it two times? Maybe this is causing the problem. If it is 200,200 why are you changing it back to 500, 500? If you want it at 500,500, remove the first two statements which set the position at 200, 200, or remove the other two statements which set it as 500, 500.

Comment: Hi Again. Thank-you for your response. My previous comment was incorrect so I have made my next comment part of my original question. I did this because I am limited to the number of characters I can use in the comment area.

Comment: I am amazed that such a simple requirement  - to move a a cursor and for it to remain in the position you move it to - is so difficult to do. VB.net and the whole framework is rubbish if a simple task like this has no answer anywhere on the net. Even to debug the underlying methods in the base classes that may be causing this problem requires you to purchase the Reflector product - what about microsoft providing a complete product.

Comment: No product is needed! A bad workman blaims his tools. There will be a problem in your code only! For me it is alright! I have made 5-10 programs with such requirement and it works perfectly!

Comment: My entire code is above and most of that is generated - there is one line I have written  Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(abc)
and that is the line that you gave me. And I also noted on a previous comment of yours that -  "This is no co-incidence that your code and mine both are getting the same error, " so you are having the problem. so this contrary to what you are saying now which is that it works perfectly. I am sorry to become so frustrated but it is such a simple issue &  I am so frustrated that there appears to be no answer.

Comment: I said your code and the one which I gave you. That means nothing is wrong in the code that I gave you or you wrote for setting cursor position. It's the problem in the code that you have written other than this. And I will see your other code when I get time. Be cool and stay calm!

Comment: There is no other code that I have written - the entire code is above in the question space. And it does not work. If you run it, it will most likely do the same on your system. Staying cool is hard but very good advice.

Comment: Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
                    Cursor.Position = btnReport.PointToScreen(New Point(btnReport.Width / 2, btnReport.Height / 2))
                    Application.DoEvents()