# Onscreen cursor positioning with user's input

Tags: c#, navigation, cursor, mouse, coordinates

I am trying to write a code that allows the user to enter X and Y coordinates for the mouse cursor location.

As soon as the user hits enter , the mouse cursor should move to the location pointed at by coordinates.

Could anyone help me in mapping the entered coordinates to cursor location.

I want to know how to update the mouse cursor's location.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: atleast u could have google'ed once, Here is the first result : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050825/how-to-move-mouse-cursor-using-c