# Using program in the background (C#)

Tags: background

e.g: a game is running and when I press a button, I want my program to show up.

another example : I'm on my desktop and when I press a button, I want my cursor to move to a specific position.

how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using windows, and using c# to develop the application.
1. You will have to develop a window form application keep it running. write a global mouse event handler, when you detect a mouse click on certain target area, bring your app to front

[Global mouse event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607133/global-mouse-event-handler)

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
this.Show();
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

2. move mose cursor, you could refer to api mentioned below post

[How to move mouse cursor using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050825/how-to-move-mouse-cursor-using-c)