# mouse control from another computer in c#

Tags: c#, controls, mouse

I am writing a program similar to team viewer, which is an application that allows one computer to control other (by viewing the screen and able to move his mouse and control his keyboard).

In order to do so i have managed to share the screen of a computer with another one, and the only thing left is to enable the mouse control. The program is written in c#. The screen sharing is working using 'ffmpeg' library.

The details that i have about the second computer, in case i am the computer that is willing to "take control" of the other, is his 'ip' address.
Does anyone know how to do so or where can i found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [How to move mouse cursor using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050825/how-to-move-mouse-cursor-using-c) it should get you started.

You will need to create some kind of protocol / transport to issue the remote calls. But this shows you how to interract with the mouse programaticly.