# C# Move Mouse Cursor to a Specific Position on Screen for Windows 10 64bit

Tags: c#, mouse

I tried this but I think it's for 32bit Windows only.

[How to move mouse cursor using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050825/how-to-move-mouse-cursor-using-c)

I am getting lots of red underline errors like "Cursor does not contain a definition for Position" and "Rectangle does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments"

```
private void MoveCursor()
{
   // Set the Current cursor, move the cursor's Position,
   // and set its clipping rectangle to the form. 

   this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
   Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
   Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
}
```

Searched older threads but I think the code is outdated and doesn't work in Windows 64 bit OS. So I'm looking for new code if there is any.

Comment: Please include the namespace USINGs aswell. It's hard to decipher this way.

Comment: there are no special usings

Comment: Thats okay, but how would we know what rectangle class are you using? What kind of cursor etc. I assume its from System.Drawing but it's not obvious

Comment: I just copy pasted the code for what I'm trying to do. That is move the desktop mouse cursor to a specific location on screen. I don't know which rectangle class it is referring to. The cursor I'm talking about is the mouse that you move on your desktop to click on stuff. To me, it's also not obvious because no specific using was described in the older threads.

Comment: If you hover your mouse on a classname it will display the fully qualified name with namespace etc. But lets skip ahead, forget what I asked. What kind of application is this? WPF? WinForms?

Comment: I hovered. It says Rectangle.Rectangle(). This is WPF.

Answer (score 0):

The example you are referencing is for moving the cursor by a specific amount, it is over-engineered if you just want to move the mouse to a specific position.

The code works on a 64 bit OS, but you need access to Windows Forms which is not available in every version of .NET.

At the top of the file you need to add

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
```

You also need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms to your project if it is not already included. The Cursor class is in `System.Windows.Forms` and the Point class is in `System.Drawing`.

The code is also supposed to exist inside a Form class, like if you created a new form through the IDE and then added some code to it. That is why it assumes a Cursor property already exists.

If all you want to do is move the cursor to a specific position on screen, you only need this one line and it doesn't need to be inside a Form:

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
```

Replace `x` and `y` with the coordinates you need or set them as `int` variables. Position is a static property so you don't need to create an instance of Cursor first. But Cursor is still a class in System.Windows.Forms so you still need to be `using` it and have a reference to it in your project.