# Prevent screen from sleeping with C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, user-input

I have created a small C# console app to move the pointer around the screen, in the hope that this would prevent the screen from sleeping / locking after a few minutes. Unfortunately the screen still goes to sleep after a few minutes.

Does anyone know if it's actually possible to write something in C# which will act like user input (either mouse or keyboard), and prevent the screen from sleeping / locking automatically?

Here is what I have, which I thought might do the trick:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

    static Random rnd = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Rectangle screenRes = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        int widtMax = screenRes.Width;
        int heighMax = screenRes.Height;

        int w;
        int h;

        do
        {
            while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                w = rnd.Next(1, widtMax);
                h = rnd.Next(1, heighMax);

                SetCursorPos(w, h);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're actual goal is to prevent the screensaver running/monitor powering off, use the function that's designed for you to tell windows that - `SetThreadExecutionState`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665332/how-do-i-prevent-screen-savers-and-sleeps-during-my-program-execution)

Comment: Annoyingly this has been asked before without answer and the OP doesn't have enough rep to be altruist and put a bounty on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282770/stop-screensaver-programmatically

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can make use of [`SetThreadExecutionState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208(VS.85).aspx)

> Enables an application to inform the system that it is in use, thereby
> preventing the system from entering sleep or turning off the display
> while the application is running.

**Remarks**

> Calling `SetThreadExecutionState` without `ES_CONTINUOUS` simply resets
> the idle timer; to keep the display or system in the working state,
> the thread must call `SetThreadExecutionState` periodically.
>
> To run properly on a power-managed computer, applications such as fax
> servers, answering machines, backup agents, and network management
> applications must use both `ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED` and `ES_CONTINUOUS` when
> they process events. Multimedia applications, such as video players
> and presentation applications, must use `ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED` when they
> display video for long periods of time without user input.
> Applications such as word processors, spreadsheets, browsers, and
> games do not need to call `SetThreadExecutionState`.

**DllImport**

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,SetLastError = true)]
static extern EXECUTION_STATE SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE esFlags);
```

**Enums**

```
[FlagsAttribute]
public enum EXECUTION_STATE :uint
{
     ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040,
     ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000,
     ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002,
     ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001
     // Legacy flag, should not be used.
     // ES_USER_PRESENT = 0x00000004
}
```

**Usage**

```
void PreventSleep ()
{
    // Prevent Idle-to-Sleep (monitor not affected) (see note above)
    SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED);
}
```

UPDATE 02/08/2021:

In case anyone is looking for a complete example, here is a project I found on github that has implemented this: https://github.com/pedrolcl/screensaver-disabler

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. My question wasn't actually a true reflection of what I was after - I wanted to prevent the screen from locking as opposed to preventing the system from going to sleep. Any way, I achieved this with `SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS);` after you pointed out to use `SetThreadExecutionState`. Thanks!

Comment: Do we need to undo this change when the app closes ? Or are we supposed to call `PreventSleep()` at regular intervals ?

Comment: @mrid https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate, check out the flag comments

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks. I went through that link. I'm making a monitoring software that would display a dashboard. So I should just use `ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED` along with `ES_CONTINUOUS ` and call it periodically. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @mrid as far i know, it should be good until you set it otherwise, or someone else does. So in short, one call should do

Comment: `SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS)` still does the trick for preventing the lock screen during RDP for Server 2016!

Comment: @TheGeneral Can this bypass windows domain policy for screen lock?

Comment: @Ally: yes it does

Comment: I need the OS to keep rendering new frames of apps but I don't actually need the monitor to be visible. so for that use-case I should use `ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED` right?