# C# cursor moving doesn't avoid screen saver

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

I've made a little program with windows forms that moves the cursor every now and then to avoid the screen saver to activate, but even if I see the cursor being moved the screen saver still gets activated.

I'm using the following commands:

```
Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
Thread.Sleep(500);
Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + 50, Cursor.Position.Y + 50);
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Time between sleeps and distances are high to see the actual movement.

Is there a way to avoid screen savers with automatic movements of the cursor as tried before?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045701/prevent-screen-from-sleeping-with-c-sharp

Comment: It's not the changing mouse position that prevents a screen saver; it's receiving input from the user. From the screen saver's perspective, changing the mouse position is only a side-effect.